# Bind Angular JS ui-bootstrap dropdown toggle to ng-model

Tags: html, angularjs, data-binding, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to use the angularjs bootstrap dropdown toggle on a form, and i need to be able to  bind the selected item back to a model for a new "organisation" in my application.

Here's my js module i'm using to create all my controls:

```
var Controls = angular.module('PulseControls', ['ui.bootstrap']);

var booleanButtonCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.radioModel = true;  
};

var currencyDropDownButtonCtrl = function($scope) {
    $scope.currencies = [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'US Dollar'
    }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'Euro'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'Australian Dollar'
}];    
};
```

Here's my starting code for my CreateNewOrganisation controller

```
function CreateOrganisationController($scope, $http, $window) {
    $scope.newOrganisation = {
        isActive: true,
};
```

and finally, here's my html code snippet, which includes a  for "Status" and a  for Currency, both of which use ui-bootstrap...

```
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Status</label><br />
            <div ng-controller="booleanButtonCtrl">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary"
                            data-ng-model="newOrganisation.isActive"
                            btn-radio="true">
                        Active
                    </button>
                    <button type="button"
                            class="btn btn-primary"
                            data-ng-model="newOrganisation.isActive"
                            btn-radio="false">
                        Dormant
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Currency</label>
            <div class="dropdown" data-ng-controller="dropDownButtonCtrl">
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">Please select<span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li ng-repeat="currency in currencies">
                            <a ng-model = "newOrganisation.currency">{{currency.name}}</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

The approach taken in the Status  works nicely, but I can't get the dropdown control for Currency to work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you post a plunker with your code? It'd be a lot easier to troubleshoot.

Answer (score 2):

```
<div class="dropdown" data-ng-controller="dropDownButtonCtrl">
```

I suspect the value for data-ng-controller here should be

```
currencyDropDownButtonCtrl
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a late response but nevertheless here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pOKiQ4BKk4kjO4PY3wEQ?p=preview) to accomplish this. Please note that the model in the controller that contains all the countries data does not have an ID for all the countries. Rather I only added id values for the first 9 countries in the model (NOT AS SEEN IN THE DROPDOWN which is sorted). So you could pick China, India and Brazil to test.

```
    var testController = ['$scope', '$http',
  function($scope, $http) {

    $scope.status = 'loading...';
    $scope.country = "Select Country";
    $scope.data = {
        "locations": {}
    };
    $scope.selectedCountryId = "1";
    $scope.onCountrySelect = function(selectedCountry){
      //$scope.country = selectedCountry.country;
      $scope.selectedCountryId = selectedCountry.id;
    }
  $scope.selectInitial = function(id){
      for (var i = 0; i < $scope.data.locations.countries.length; i++) {
        if ($scope.data.locations.countries[i].id == id)
        {
          return $scope.data.locations.countries[i].country;
        }
      }
      //$scope.country = selectedCountry.country;
    }
    //load JSON data
    $http.get('countries.json')
      .then(function(res) {
        $scope.data.locations.countries = res.data;
        $scope.status = "loaded "+$scope.data.locations.countries.length+" countries.";
        $scope.$apply();
      });


  }
];
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested in a template only solution:

```html
<div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
    {{ selected || 'Select an option...' }}
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
    <li role="menuitem" ng-repeat="option in options">
        <a href="" ng-click="selected === null" ng-if="$index === 0">Select an option...</a>
        <a href="" ng-click="selected === option">{{ option }}</a>
        <input type="hidden" name="options" ng-model="selected" required>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You use a hidden input with the `ng-model` set like you normally would and use an `ng-click` to bind the model to a given value, from an `ng-repeat` for example. The rest of the markup is copy/paste from ui-boostrap template example.